# Android - Using updateChildren() with HashMap

Tags: android, firebase

I am working with a listview and an arrayadapter where I am using the *simple_list_item_multiple_choice*, so I can select multiple items in my listview.

**What I want to do**: I want all selected items to be inserted in my Firebase database. For that I am using a hashmap.

**What I have done**:

```
 addUsersButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        HashMap<String, Object> drivers = new HashMap<>();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int cntChoice = userList.getCount();
            SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = userList.getCheckedItemPositions();

            for (int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++) {
                if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                    drivers.put("drivers", userList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                }

            }
            userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null)).child("routes").child(key).updateChildren(drivers);


        }
    });
```

**Problem**: This only adds one of the selected items to the database. I don't know why.

Comment: Yes, it is overriden the item. So no matter how many selected, it only shows one in the database, as it overrides the data.

Comment: When I use setValue, everything else in that node get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With each iteration of the selected items, you are calling:

```
drivers.put("drivers", userList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
```

Which will overwrite the `"drivers"` value in the `HashMap` with the item at the given position, thus your `HashMap` only ever contains one item with the key of `"drivers"`. This is because [`HashMap` keys are unique and calling `put()` replaces the previous value associated with the given key if it already exists](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)).

Therefore, you'll need to add each item to the `HashMap` with a unique ID and then call `updateChildren()` on the `drivers` child node instead:

```
addUsersButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    HashMap<String, Object> drivers = new HashMap<>();
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int cntChoice = userList.getCount();
        SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = userList.getCheckedItemPositions();

        for (int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++) {
            if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                String uniqueId = usersRef.push().getKey(); // this doesn't actually push any data to the database
                drivers.put(uniqueId, userList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()); // use the unique ID to add to the HashMap
            }
        }
        userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null))
            .child("routes")
            .child(key)
            .child("drivers") // specify "drivers" child node here
            .updateChildren(drivers);
    }
});
```

This way, each item will be added to the `HashMap` with a unique ID and this `HashMap` will then be pushed onto the `drivers` child node.